# SXA search scope query not updating custom field name

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

In the `scope query` field, for the `SXA` search, I have entered a query like `+custom:Divisions|{C24CDE42-XXXX-4225-9F5F-65D6953EF1C7}`. Now I check the Solr query log it builds the query like `?q=divisions:(c24cde4271ed42259f5f65d6953ef1b9)` and it gives an error as `Solr Error : [undefined field divisions]`.

I checked the solr, and the field is available as `divisions_sm` so I tried to modify the scope query like `+custom:Divisions_sm|{C24CDE42-XXXX-4225-9F5F-65D6953EF1C7}` but it still takes the `?q=divisions:(c24cde4271ed42259f5f65d6953ef1b9)`.

I thought it was a cache issue so I restarted my pods but still, due to missing `_sm` in the solr query the data is not coming.

So how can I mention this in the scope query field so that the solr query can be `divisions_sm`?

Comment: Is in the Schema file the field name divisons_sm?

Comment: This is not computed field so we did not set this any where on template the field name is Divisions but Solr is indexing it as divisions_sm